What's the point of making Shell.Items a getter only Bindable Property?
Shell.Items Property:
public System.Collections.Generic.IList<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellItem> Items { get; }

Shell.ItemsProperty Field:
public static readonly Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableProperty ItemsProperty;

According to the documentation,

The purpose of bindable properties is to provide a property system that supports data binding ...

My basic understanding is that when a property is declared as bindable, I expect to be able to do something like this in XAML:
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSourceInViewModel}">

<Label Text={Binding SomeTextProperty} />

...etc

In case of Shell Items, I can't do something like this:
<Shell Items = "{Binding ShellItemsSource}">

I'm assuming this is because it's a getter only property with no setter. But if this is the case, then why make it a Bindable Property in the first place?

If i remember correctly its a readonly BindableProperty using CreateReadOnly

@FreakyAli, not sure what the significance of that? But it appears to me that all Maui BindableProperty fields are marked as readonly static, if that's what you're referring to. That's including the ItemsSource of CollectionView.

What I meant is it's not a get type it's a literal readonly using BindablePropertyKey https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/307941eaa5ec2f57f18f495d465d1371dce90398/src/Controls/src/Core/Shell/Shell.cs#L624

What kind of layout do you want to achieve with shell.items? Can you provide relevant code?

@ShuowenHe-MSFT, I wanted to understand the reasoning behind declaring Shell.Items as a BindableProperty when it is not possible to bind it in XAML as I described in my post?

How did you use Shell.Items in your AppShell.xaml file?

@ShuowenHe-MSFT, good question. Currently, all Shell Items are hard coded in the XAML file. For example, TabBar, FlyoutItem etc.. I'm not sure if I should call this binding.

You can provide the complete code of the AppShell.xaml file, I will try to reproduce your problem
